# Replacing values in a string from another table without nested REPLACE

Tags: sql, t-sql

In one table, I have long strings which contain a series of tokens that need to be replaced from values in a number of columns in a separate customer table.  There are around 30 tokens but below is a representation of it.  So for example, the FName value in Table2 needs to replace the [fname] token in the string in Table1 and so on.

I can do it as below with a series of nested REPLACE statements, but it's ugly and unruly given the number of tokens that need to be replaced.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated?

Notes: I'm doing this in T-SQL.  And the token name doesn't always match the column name 100%.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (StringtoReplace NVARCHAR(200))
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (Greeting NVARCHAR(30), FName NVARCHAR(30), LName NVARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES ('[greeting] [fname] [lname] Here is the message')

INSERT INTO #Table2 
VALUES ('Hello','John','Smith'),
       ('Hi','Fred','Jones'),
       ('Howdy','Sue','Brown')

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t1.StringToReplace,'[greeting]',t2.Greeting),'[fname]',t2.fname),'[lname]',t2.lname) AS UpdatedString
FROM #Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY #Table2 t2
```

Here's the required output.

```
UpdatedString
-------------------------------------------
Hello John Smith Here is the message
Hi Fred Jones Here is the message
Howdy Sue Brown Here is the message
```

Comment: Side note: `APPLY` doesn't seem to be necessary here. A `CROSS JOIN` should be enough.

Comment: In my actual scenario, I'm not using CROSS APPLY or CROSS JOIN.  This was just for quick illustration here.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative would be successively `CROSS APPLY` the replacements.  Is this better?  Idk.  It performs the calculation in the `FROM` clause and cleans up the `SELECT` list.  It returns the correct output as well

```
drop table if exists #Table1;
go
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (StringtoReplace NVARCHAR(200));

drop table if exists #Table2;
go
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (Greeting NVARCHAR(30), FName NVARCHAR(30), LName NVARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES ('[greeting] [fname] [lname] Here is the message');

INSERT INTO #Table2 
VALUES ('Hello','John','Smith'),
       ('Hi','Fred','Jones'),
       ('Howdy','Sue','Brown');

SELECT v3.StringtoReplace UpdatedString
FROM #Table1 t1
     cross apply #Table2 t2
     cross apply (values (replace(t1.StringToReplace, '[greeting]', t2.Greeting))) v1(StringtoReplace)
     cross apply (values (replace(v1.StringToReplace, '[fname]', [fname]))) v2(StringtoReplace)
     cross apply (values (replace(v2.StringToReplace, '[lname]', [lname]))) v3(StringtoReplace);
```

```
UpdatedString
Hello John Smith Here is the message
Hi Fred Jones Here is the message
Howdy Sue Brown Here is the message
```

If instead of temp tables the rows were stored in physical tables, then you could create a reusable inline table valued function, itvf.  Using the itvf the query is only 3 lines of code and it produces the same output as before.

```
drop table if exists dbo.test_Table1;
go
CREATE TABLE dbo.test_Table1 (StringtoReplace NVARCHAR(200));

drop table if exists dbo.test_Table2;
go
CREATE TABLE dbo.test_Table2 (Greeting NVARCHAR(30), FName NVARCHAR(30), LName NVARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO dbo.test_Table1 VALUES ('[greeting] [fname] [lname] Here is the message');

INSERT INTO dbo.test_Table2 
VALUES ('Hello','John','Smith'),
       ('Hi','Fred','Jones'),
       ('Howdy','Sue','Brown');

drop function if exists dbo.test_fnReplace;
go
create function dbo.test_fnReplace(
  @StringtoReplace              nvarchar(200))
returns table as return
select v3.StringtoReplace UpdatedString
from dbo.test_Table2 t2
     cross apply (values (replace(@StringtoReplace, '[greeting]', t2.Greeting))) v1(StringtoReplace)
     cross apply (values (replace(v1.StringToReplace, '[fname]', [fname]))) v2(StringtoReplace)
     cross apply (values (replace(v2.StringToReplace, '[lname]', [lname]))) v3(StringtoReplace);
go

select fnRep.UpdatedString
from dbo.test_Table1 t1
     cross apply dbo.test_fnReplace(t1.StringtoReplace) fnRep;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks.  That works too.  Although this would still require 30 replace statements, just not nested the same way.

Comment: The pattern could be made to be dynamic but then 30 is not so many if you only have to do it once.

Comment: I would think there would be fewer keystrokes to do it manually with this method versus nested REPLACE

Comment: True enough.  30 isn't terrible.  I will have to do this at a few places though, so I was hoping it could be a bit more dynamic so I could reuse it.  I do like your option though since it's a more visually appealing way of managing the nested replaces.

Comment: You've provided temp tables here.  To create a table valued function which references the 'table2' table would require making it a physical table.  It's the same columns always?  A physical table to store 'table2' data is ok?

Comment: Yes, physical tables for both is ok. Thanks.